# Best practise for boost::asio timeouts when using coroutines

Tags: c++, boost, timeout, asio

The connection attempt below creates (on my network configuration) a delay of 2 minutes because the target does not exist and the address is on a different subnet to my machine.  So I added timeout logic to limit the attempt to 5 seconds:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT
#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_COROUTINE

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/address_v4.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/executor_work_guard.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/redirect_error.hpp>

namespace this_coro = boost::asio::this_coro;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

boost::asio::awaitable<void> fail_to_connect()
{
    auto executor = co_await this_coro::executor;
    auto socket = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket{executor};
    auto ep = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{
                    boost::asio::ip::make_address_v4("192.168.1.52"),
                    80};

    auto timer = boost::asio::steady_timer{executor};
    timer.expires_after(5s);
    boost::asio::co_spawn(
        executor,
        [&]() -> boost::asio::awaitable<void> {
            auto ec = boost::system::error_code{};
            co_await timer.async_wait(boost::asio::redirect_error(boost::asio::use_awaitable, ec));
            std::cout << "Thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id()
                      << " Timer: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            if (!ec) {
                socket.close();
            }
        },
        boost::asio::detached
    );

    std::cout << "Thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id()
              << " Starting connection" << std::endl;
    co_await boost::asio::async_connect(socket,
                                        std::array{std::move(ep)},
                                        boost::asio::use_awaitable);
    timer.cancel();
}

int main()
{
    auto ctx = boost::asio::io_context{};
    auto guard = boost::asio::make_work_guard(ctx.get_executor());

    auto exception_handler = [&](auto e_ptr) {
        if (e_ptr) {
            std::rethrow_exception(e_ptr);
        }
    };

    boost::asio::co_spawn(ctx, fail_to_connect, std::move(exception_handler));
    ctx.run();
}
```

This works as expected.  As you can see from the thread ID's, using the same execution context between the two coroutines means that I'm not accessing the socket concurrently too.

```
14:58:41: Starting /home/cmannett85/workspace/build-scratch-Desktop-Debug/scratch ...
Thread ID: 140171855615808 Starting connection
Thread ID: 140171855615808 Timer: Success
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::system::system_error'
  what():  Operation canceled
14:58:46: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

However this *feels* clunky, especially compared to the non-coroutine callback-style.  Is there a better approach for timeouts using coroutines?  I'm struggling to find examples.

Comment: You could maybe use the callback style of async_await to do the cancellation, that would remove at least a few lines of boilerplate. What seems to be needed in Asio is something like [`folly::coro::collectAll()`](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/experimental/coro/README.md#concurrently-awaiting-multiple-tasks)

Comment: Found this fantastic write up on how to implement a completion token which adds a timeout to any operation: https://cppalliance.org/richard/2021/10/10/RichardsOctoberUpdate.html I haven’t tested it myself but seems to be exactly what you’re looking for

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is to lift the boilerplate into a class.

Basically just a wrapper around a timer, that can set and cancel a callback with an easier interface:

```cpp
#include "asio.hpp"

class timeout {
  asio::high_resolution_timer timer_;
  using duration = asio::high_resolution_timer::duration;

 public:
  template <typename Executor>
  timeout(Executor&& executor) : timer_(executor){};

  template <typename Executor, typename Func>
  timeout(Executor&& executor, const duration& timeout, Func&& on_timeout)
      : timer_(executor) {
    set(timeout, on_timeout);
  }

  template <typename Func>
  void set(const duration& timeout, Func&& on_timeout) {
    timer_.expires_after(timeout);  // cancels outstanding timeouts
    timer_.async_wait([&](std::error_code ec) {
      if (ec) return;
      std::cout << "cancelling\n";
      on_timeout();
    });
  }

  void cancel() { timer_.cancel(); }

  ~timeout() { timer_.cancel(); }
};
```

This can be used like this:

```cpp
tmo.set(1s, [&]() { socket.close(); });
std::size_t n = co_await asio::async_read_until(socket, incoming, '\n',
                                                asio::use_awaitable);

asio::const_buffer response(asio::buffers_begin(incoming.data()),
                            asio::buffers_begin(incoming.data()) + n);

tmo.set(1s, [&]() { socket.close(); });
co_await asio::async_write(socket, response, asio::use_awaitable);

incoming.consume(n);
```

It can be generally used with any object that supports true cancellation, which is somewhat sparsely supported. For example, the only true way to cancel an ongoing read or write on a socket is to call `close()`.

Cancelling an `async_resolve` for example, is not possible, because `cancel()` only cancels a pending operation, not an ongoing one. In other words, this doesn't work as expected:

```cpp
// does not actually cancel anything :(
tmo.set(1s, [&]() { resolver.cancel(); });
resolver.async_resolve(...);
```

Here's a full example of an echo client that stops if any of these takes more than 1 second:

- `async_connect`
- `async_read_until`
- `async_write`

As noted, `async_resolve` cannot be cancelled, and so writing a timeout for it doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps posting an exception to the coroutine's execution context would work instead?

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// clang-format off
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "sdkddkver.h"
#endif
#include "asio.hpp"
// clang-format on

using asio::ip::tcp;

class timeout {
  asio::high_resolution_timer timer_;
  using duration = asio::high_resolution_timer::duration;

 public:
  template <typename Executor>
  timeout(Executor&& executor) : timer_(executor){};

  template <typename Executor, typename Func>
  timeout(Executor&& executor, const duration& timeout, Func&& on_timeout)
      : timer_(executor) {
    set(timeout, on_timeout);
  }

  template <typename Func>
  void set(const duration& timeout, Func&& on_timeout) {
    timer_.expires_after(timeout);  // cancels outstanding timeouts
    timer_.async_wait([&](std::error_code ec) {
      if (ec) return;
      std::cout << "cancelling\n";
      on_timeout();
    });
  }

  void cancel() { timer_.cancel(); }

  ~timeout() { timer_.cancel(); }
};

asio::awaitable<void> echo_client(tcp::socket& socket, std::string_view host,
                                  std::string_view service) {
  try {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto exec = socket.get_executor();

    tcp::resolver resolver(exec);
    timeout tmo(exec);

    std::cout << "resolving...\n";
    tmo.set(1s, [&]() { resolver.cancel(); });
    auto endpoints =
        co_await resolver.async_resolve(host, service, asio::use_awaitable);

    std::cout << "connecting...\n";
    tmo.set(1s, [&]() { socket.close(); });
    co_await asio::async_connect(socket, endpoints, asio::use_awaitable);

    asio::streambuf incoming;

    for (;;) {
      std::cout << "reading... ";

      tmo.set(1s, [&]() { socket.close(); });
      std::size_t n = co_await asio::async_read_until(socket, incoming, '\n',
                                                      asio::use_awaitable);

      std::string response(asio::buffers_begin(incoming.data()),
                           asio::buffers_begin(incoming.data()) + n);

      std::cout << response;

      tmo.set(1s, [&]() { socket.close(); });
      co_await asio::async_write(socket, asio::buffer(response),
                                 asio::use_awaitable);

      incoming.consume(n);
    }
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc < 3) {
    std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " [host] [port]\n";
    return 1;
  }

  asio::io_context io_context;
  tcp::socket socket(io_context);

  asio::co_spawn(io_context, echo_client(socket, argv[1], argv[2]),
                 asio::detached);

  io_context.run();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might make sense to change the constructor of `timeout` to take a reference to a template Timer type and use that instead of constructing one.